# How to add multiple semitransparent backgrounds to single element

Tags: html, css

In my css grid, cells are highlighted on hover using semitransparent background.

Sometimes, I want to set custom background to some cells, but this conficts with the hover.
How do I add additional semitransparent background to a cell so that the two backgrounds meld together.

```css
.cell:hover {
   background: #8888;
}

.bg-danger {
   background: #f008;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell bg-danger">
    Highlighted Cell
</div>
<div class="cell">Cell</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a seperate div for the bg-danger class.

```css
.cell:hover {
   background: #8888;
}

.bg-danger {
   background: #f008;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
    <div class="bg-danger">Highlighted Cell</div>
</div>
<div class="cell">Cell</div>
```

As an alterative you can add a different hover color for the danger class

```css
.cell:hover {
   background: #8888;
}

.cell.bg-danger:hover {
   background: #a008;
}

.bg-danger {
   background: #f008;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell bg-danger">Highlighted Cell</div>
<div class="cell">Cell</div>
```